# print the values that are common from both the tables of a column

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I want to print the values that are common from both the tables of a column.

The issue is one column's substring value matches with the other column's string.

Printing the subquery alone fetches the right values (proving the substring query is correct) but I think the entire query after the where clause needs changing.

Kindly suggest.

Code:

```
select distinct sd.sourceworkitemid 
from u_prodstypetest pst, sdidata sd 
where sd.keyid1 = 'S-20210719-00000003' 
and sd.sourceworkitemid in (select substr(testmethodid,0,INSTR(testmethodid,'|',1)-1) from u_prodstypetest);
```

I want to create a substring of a value of a column in a table and compare it with a column in another table. But since it is a substring the where clause of column1=column2 does not suffice and hence I wroe the subquery to fetch the substring which if run throws an error in 'in' because the subquery return >1 values.

Comment: What do you mean by "tables of a column"? Column of a table is understandable but not the reverse tables of a column.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; `INSERT` statements for sample data; details of your expected output from the query; and the issues/errors with your existing query.

Comment: comparing sd.sourceworkitem with pst.u_prodstypetest - column that holds the same value in two different tables (only dissrence being pst.u_prodstypetest has some extra values inside it).

Comment: Why are you using a `CROSS JOIN` (legacy comma-join) on the two tables and then filtering on a substring of one of those tables in the `IN` clause? Please [edit] your question to include sample data and expected output because it is very difficult to comprehend what you are intending from just the query.

Comment: *But since it is a substring the where clause of column1=column2 does not suffice* - this is what LIKE is for. Assuming `a.a` is `orangina` and `b.b` is `gin` then you can `a JOIN b ON a.a LIKE '%'||b.b||'%'` and it will match, because *oran**gin**a* contains **gin** :D